# Validating a string to formatting rules Java

Tags: java, string, validation, format

I have to validate a string to certain formatting rules, those rules are:

`string : string : int : int` (Colons included).

How can I check that the string contains; two string, three colons and two integers in that order. Plus a string could have a space in it e.g. "hello there" and each integer could be any length.

Been trying for a while now and can't find a neat way. Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Is white space required around the colons? Can you show us any code? Sample input(s) and output(s)?

Comment: Use a Regex Matcher against the string. See [this tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/matcher.html) on the Topicfor example

Comment: Use a regexp. Or read the String javadoc and parse it (indexOf(), substring(), Character.isDigit() come to mind as useful methods).

Comment: You need to give more details about what is a "string". Does it contain special characters ? Does it contain figures ? etc

Comment: Can your strings also have colons in them? If no, you could split the string at `":"`, check whether the result has length 4 and whether the last two entries parse as an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to do the checks:

```
public boolean match(String s) {
    return s.matches("^.+ : .+ : \\d+ : \\d+$");
}
```

This tests if every part contains at least one valid character (i.e., any character for part `string` and any digit for part `int`) with `:` as a delimiter between them.

**Test**

```
System.out.println(match("blub : test : 100 : 111")); // true
System.out.println(match("1 : 1 : 1 : 1")); // true
System.out.println(match("blub : test : foo : bar")); // false
System.out.println(match("blub : test : 0.1 : 0.1")); // false
System.out.println(match("this is another : test : 100 : 111")); // true
System.out.println(match("!\"§$%&/()=?) : .; : : : ; : 100 : 111")); // true
System.out.println(match(" :  : 100 : 111")); // false
```

Mind the test `match("!\"§$%&/()=?) : .; : : : ; : 100 : 111")`. It returns true, because the additional `:` are part of the second `string` part.

Comment: Brilliant!! worked straight away. I'd been looking at regular expressions but didn't know I could add them together like that. Thank you

Answer (score -2):

make use of regular expressions - class matcher, that should work fine.

for example:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

   public class ValidateInput
{

/// validate first name

public static Boolean validateFirstName(String firstName)
{
return firstName.matches("[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*";
}//// end method validateFirstName
}

///// 


public void main(String[] args)
{
 //// get user input

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please, enter first name: ");

//// validate user input and display error message

System.out.print("\nValidate Result:");

if(!ValidateInput.validateFirstName(firstName())
System.out.print("Invalide first name");

}
```

Comment: How does this relate to the question?

Comment: it's an example of what he wants, away of showing the use of regular expressions

Comment: An answer on Stack Overflow should be a solution specific to the original question.